# Should the [flash] tag be (eventually) renamed?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

With the [sunset](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-adobe-systems-flash/adobe-to-pull-plug-on-flash-ending-an-era-idUSKBN1AA22R) of the Flash technology, we should probably make some updates to the tag on this site, and since there are other meanings of the word flash, I'm wondering if we should free up the tag for another use, and make an [adobe-flash] tag to hold old questions about the defunct technology (after 2020), or (in the mean time) about converting Flash products to other technologies.

What does the community think?

Comment: You actually think it makes sense to start discussing something now that's not going to be relevant until *at least* 2020? Are there any other strong contenders for a tag named [flash] that make this a pressing issue?

Comment: You can tell your grand-children about it, they'll love a good war-story.  That doesn't need a different [tag].

Comment: I never said it was a pressing issue. note (eventually) in the title.

Comment: The fact that Adobe will stop releasing updates doesn't mean the technology will vanish. People will be developing with it long after support for it drops.

Answer (score 12):

Two things:

- It's not 2020 *yet*.  Believe it or not there will be companies using Flash until they literally can't afford to anymore.
- Developers who inherit a largely ActionScript codebase (which Flash is written in) would still want guidance on how things work, if they have to reverse engineer what was written.

So no, I see no reason for the tag to go anywhere.  It still has value.

Comment: We still have an active [[tag:fortran77]] tag, after all. Hard to argue that hasn't been obsoleted/subsumed.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I have associates who work at NCAR who still have Fortran rattling around in their atmospheric model pipeline.  Definitely *not* obsolete from their standpoint, but also, Fortran isn't like Flash; Flash definitely doesn't have a future, whereas Fortran is *still* getting updates.

Comment: I don't think they're updating the Fortran 77 standard anymore... That's why I chose a version-specific tag.

Comment: And that's as it should be. However, if fortran77 was a common enough english word that it could end up referring to another technology (or other method, think memory flashing for the flash example) in the future, it might be worth renaming it to make room.

Comment: @NH.:  How about we cross that bridge when we need to instead of trying to anticipate the future?  The platform's flexible enough to handle a change like this.  Let it.